# Determine m and c if the shaded region has area 4.5 units^2

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

The area between the two graphs,
\begin{align} 
y = -x^2 + 2x + 3 
\end{align}
&
\begin{align} 
y = mx + c
\end{align}

is 4.5 units^2.

They intersect twice, at (-1,0) & at an unknown point.
I want to find the values for m & c that make the area between the two graphs 4.5 units^2 (Refer to image for graph).

I found that m = c through:

\begin{align}
\ m & = {\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}} \\
 & = {\frac{c - 0}{0 - (-1)}} \\
 & = {\frac{c}{1}} \\
 & = c
\end{align}

When I make the unknown point of intersection A(a,b) and when i find the area under both graphs separately i get:

For the parabola:
\begin{align} 
A = \frac{-a^3}{3} + a^2 + 3a + \frac{5}{3} 
\end{align}

And for the linear equation, i get either:
\begin{align} 
A = \frac{ma^2}{2} + ma - \frac{m}{2} +1 
\end{align}
when using integration and:
\begin{align} 
A = \frac{1}{2} * (a+1) * (b) 
\end{align}
When using just the formula for the area of a triangle.

and since:

\begin{align} 
b = -x^2 + 2x + 3 
\end{align}

The area under the linear graph is:

\begin{align} 
A &= \frac{1}{2} * (a+1) * (-a^2 + 2a + 3 ) \\
& = \frac{-a^3+a^2+5a+3}{2}
\end{align}

So:
\begin{align} 
4.5 = (\frac{-a^3}{3} + a^2 + 3a + \frac{5}{3} ) - (\frac{-a^3+a^2+5a+3}{2})
\end{align} 
which results in a = 2

And if a = 2, then b = 3

Therefore:

\begin{align}
\ m & = {\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}} \\
 & = {\frac{3 - 0}{2 - (-1)}} \\
 & = {\frac{3}{3}} \\
 & = 1
\end{align}

So m, c = 1

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfDG7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the other point if intersection to be $A=(x,y)$. Find the area under the parabola from $(-1,0)$ to $A$. Now find the same for the straight line, this is easier because this is a triangle. Subtract that latter from the former and equate that with $4.5$. You have already eliminated one variable because $m=c$. So solve for the other one.

Comment: Thank you! Does what i did above look all correct?

Comment: Process seems fine.